# I found a solution to my elantech multi-touch bug but it involves a patch to kernel 3.9

Tags: drivers, kernel, touchpad, multi-touch, elantech

Here's [the Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442).

Kendatsuba in [comment 77](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/comments/77) offers a patch that works, and people with the same laptop as me (Samsung np780z5e) confirm it works. The problem is the age of the patch- if I'm understanding the fix, people patched kernel 3.8 and downloaded. I'm guessing that downloading and using a patch that old would be dangerous? Is there another way to apply this fix?

I tried accessing the elan.i2c.ko file directly but couldn't. Any suggestions on what to try next? Thanks.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running and which kernel version (`uname -r`). Normally these kind of patches make it upstream and newer kernels should include this already. Maybe this is a x-y-problem and updating your kernel fixes your issue with the elantech bug.

Comment: Hi Thomas- I'm running 16.04LTS with the  4.13.0-36-generic kernel. I've got the same behavior described- only have right click, left click, basic movement, and tap to click, with two exceptions- I can scroll, and instead of saying PS/2 Elantech Touchpad it shows up as ETPS/2 Elantech touchpad. So I suppose some of the patch made it upstream. I don't have the three-finger gestures others have mentioned however.

I see that the latest mainline version is 4.16-rc2. Are you suggesting that updating to that would fix this bug?

Thanks for replying Thomas.

Comment: I think you should open a second question that describes your actual problem you are facing with the touchpad. Include desktop used, if xorg or wayland...